# tweepy time filtering(python)

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using tweepy which is a Python library for Twitter, to get the tweets of an account. problem is- it shows all the tweets the user has tweeted regardless of the time.

How can I filter it so it only shows tweets tweeted in the past 10 minutes(even somthing like 'tweeted at 5:30' would work)? I've checked the [documentation](http://joshthecoder.github.com/tweepy/docs/api.html#status-methods) but found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of searching by time directly through the API, but you can use `API.user_timeline` to get the most recent tweets for a user.  You can then store these in a local database and do what you like with them (e.g. select just tweets since a particular time).

I don't know what you mean by "all tweets the user has tweeted" as there's no API method for this that I know of.  All the API methods have some kind of restriction on the number of tweets returned.

From the docs you linked to:

> API.user_timeline([id/user_id/screen_name][, since_id][, max_id][, count][, page])
>
> Returns the 20 most recent statuses posted from the
>   authenticating  user or the user
>   specified. It’s also possible to
>   request another user’s timeline via
>   the id parameter.

Comment: @seb- that could work but `print api.user_timeline('tweetneag4',52657504580149248)` only returns a bench of keys like `tweepy.models.Status object at 0xb6f785ec`